# Generate XML from XML schema xsd in 4GL Progess OpenEdge?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

iam using 4GL in Progress OpenEdge 11.3 and i want to write a xml file from xsd  schema file.
Can i generate a xml file from a XML Schema (xsd) with 4GL Progress OpenEdge?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a method called READ-XMLSCHEMA (and it's counterpart WRITE-XMLSCHEMA).

These can be applied to both TEMP-TABLES and ProDataSets (depending of the complexity of the xml).

The ProDataSet documentation, [found here](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvpds/dvpds.pdf), contains quite a lot information about this. There's also a book called [Working with XML](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvxml/dvxml.pdf) that can help you.

This is the basic syntax of READ-XMLSCHEMA (when working with datasets):

```
READ-XMLSCHEMA ( source-type, { file | memptr | handle | longchar }, 
override-default-mapping [, field-type-mapping [, verify-schema-mode ] ] ).
```

A basic example would be:

```
DATASET ds:READ-XMLSCHEMA("file", "c:\temp\file.xsd", FALSE).
```

However since you need to work with the actual XML you also will have to handle data. That data is handled in the TEMP-TABLES contained withing the Dataset. It might be easier to start with creating a static ProDataSet that corresponds to the schema and then handle it's data whatever way you want.